# Adding Bcc to Email sending using .NET SmtpClient?

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtpclient

When sending email using the SMTPClient class in ASP.NET C#, how can I add bcc to the email?  How can I add bcc to a MailMessage instance?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
MailAddress addressTo = new MailAddress("to@someone.com");
MailAddress addressFrom = new MailAddress("from@someone.com");
MailAddress addressBCC = new MailAddress("bcc@someone.com");

MailMessage MyMessage = new MailMessage(addressFrom, addressTo );
MyMessage.Bcc.Add(addressBCC);
```

Answer (score 14):

You're looking for the aptly-named [`Bcc` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.bcc.aspx):

```
message.Bcc.Add("You@Example.com");
```

Answer (score 3):

Here i will explain how to **send email with cc and bcc** using asp.net c# application.

```
 MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(smtpUser, toAddress);
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cc))
 {
    mailMessage.CC.Add(cc);
 }
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bcc))
 {
    mailMessage.Bcc.Add(bcc);
 }
```

For full example http://www.stepover-f10.com/2014/01/how-send-email-with-cc-and-bcc-with-authentication-using-aspnet-csharp-example-source-code.aspx
click this link.

Comment: The link is now uncooperative.