# sending email to multiple addresses,but not see other user addresses

Tags: c#, email

I am using the SmtpClient in C# and I will be sending to potentially 1000s of email addresses.
I want to only the recipient's email address is displayed.
for example:

I send email to aa@xx.xx,bb@xx.xx,cc@xx.xx,dd@xx.xx...
aa can only see the email address aa@xx.xx,bb can only see the email address bb@xx.xx.
they don't know I send the email to others.

Comment: Have you ever heard of bcc?

Comment: Show the code you use.

Comment: Using BCC will not satisfy the requirement. There is no way I know of to meet the requirement given though.

Comment: I have heard of bcc.But I don't know what to do next

Comment: Please post the code. It will help you to get it resolved faster.

Comment: BCC should work as it doesn't include the other email addresses in the email headers. Maybe have a look at this for C#, assuming you are using the built-in MailMessage class http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474472/adding-bcc-to-email-sending-using-net-smtpclient

Answer (score 0):

Use `mail.BCC` instead of `mail.To` for users who's addresses you dont't want to display to others

Comment: "I want to only the recipient's email address is displayed" How would you display the users address if it is in the BCC?

Comment: @Onots I mean this. But my English is poor.I can't discript my ideas well